# Finding what antenna is used on a breakout board

Tags: wireless, antenna

I am using http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo board for wirelss communication. I am curious as to which antenna is being used on the board. Could someone please point me to the correct BOM? Also who makes these boards? I know who makes the chip but I see these boards on ebay and several other places? So who is the original designer of this breakout board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [data sheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf) for an IC is usually a good place to look for reference designs

[image]
[image]

The [manufacturer's website](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) is also a source for information about antenna design - [Quarterwave printed monopole antenna for 2.4GHz](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/19934/4/17115143)

See also

- [Why does an antenna trace have this shape?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34605/2191)
- http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra117d/swra117d.pdf
- http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN697.pdf